# Store moodledata on S3 and manage using AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, moodle

I would like to store my moodledata folder on S3 bucket and share with multiple EC2 instances for autoscaling.

So without using S3fs, I want to manage this moodledata on S3 bucket using AWS SDK for PHP.

Also, I have searched many forums but I did not get any solution with AWS SDK for PHP.  Regards,

Comment: Look Amazon Elastic File System (EFS) instead of s3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_objectfs which almost does this. It does not replace the file system but shifts files to S3 based on critera. Example if file size is greater than 10kb. You will still need a shared file system but would be able to keep the cost down by shifting old and large files off to S3. In AWS the best way to have a shared file system is EFS service. It would be challenging to completely replace the file system with S3 as S3 is not a file system but an object store.